# Electrical spark generator

Tags: mosfet, analog, transformer, high-voltage

I need a spark between two pins with 5mm gap.
And I use this circuit:

[image]
Things changeable:

- the characteristics of the transformer (ratio, coil windings, coil gap and ...).
- The type of the MOSFET.

How to change these in a way that spark can heat the air between two pins up to 363°C? (minimum alcohol combustion temperature)

I think the question is now clear and narrow. and I don't think it still deserves downvotes.

Comment: I am laughing so hard right now. It's a potato gun. I'm much more forgiving to potato gun-makers than I am to mad bombers.

Comment: I don't know why you want to do it this way while you can use a simple christmas lamp!!!

Comment: Just remove the glass cover and put it in enough explosive charge.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What do you mean "crash and be cut into pieces"? How about a "Piezoelectric spark generator"? http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Piezo_igniter.jpg

Comment: @Roh see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are attempting to ignite a fuel-air mixture in an enclosed space using an electrical spark. I wonder if there is an existing solution.......

The schematic you made is a classic engine ignition circuit, but as you discovered it takes a fair bit of energy. We want our potato cannon to be portable so a bigger battery isn't practical.

A much simpler solution is a piezo barbecue lighter. Push button -> spark at other end. No batteries required, you can get one for $10 anywhere that sells / services large gas barbecues.

Comment: and just to prove its been done - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAyM8Iet1O8

Comment: What if I don't want an piezo spark generator?

Comment: Then do it the easy way and use a long lighter like this:https://www.dollartree.com/Click-n-Flame-Refillable-Long-Reach-Butane-Lighters/p305704/index.pro  Just drill a hole in your spud cannon and epoxy the sucker right on in.  The lighter even has a trigger, so you can aim the spud and shoot where you want it to go.